# How would I change this code to work with a specified player range instead of using a Raycast?

Tags: c#

Currently, my inventory system works by the player looking at the item with a crosshair, pressing 'F'and picking it up. This was made using a raycast to detect when the player looks at the item.

However, because my game is now a third person I would like it to pick up items by detecting when an item is in the player's range, player press 'F', and picks it up.

Previously I tried doing it with when an item is in the players OnTriggerEnter range, but it didn't work that well.

Here's the code that I'm working with:

```
    RaycastHit hit;
    Ray ray = playerController.playerCamera.ViewportPointToRay(new Vector3(0.5F, 0.5F, 0));

    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 2.5f))
    {
        Transform objectHit = hit.transform;

        if (objectHit.CompareTag("Respawn"))
        {
            if ((detectedItem == null || detectedItem.transform != objectHit) && objectHit.GetComponent<PickItem>() != null)
            {
                PickItem itemTmp = objectHit.GetComponent<PickItem>();

                //Check if item is in availableItemsList
                for (int i = 0; i < availableItems.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (availableItems[i].itemName == itemTmp.itemName)
                    {
                        detectedItem = itemTmp;
                        detectedItemIndex = i;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            detectedItem = null;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        detectedItem = null;
    }
```

Comment: What were the problems you had with triggering? You said it didn't work, that doesn't give us any clue as to how far you got

Comment: Raycasts can have a limiting distance so like Charleh says you haven’t really defined the problem

Comment: @Charleh You're right, I didn't explain much about what I've tried. Sorry about that. I have figured it out though but thanks for the attempted assist.

Comment: Hi, I see you are using the [tag:UnityScript] tag, please note that this is (as explained in the tag info) a deprecated scripting language made by Unity, and not an encompassing term for all scripts in Unity. Your question is about C#. Please only use this tag if you're working on legacy code using the actual language UnityScript. This keeps the questions and tags in line with each other :)

Comment: @Remy Ahhh, Got it I'll change it! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I've figured this out. To solve this I ended up creating an empty game object under my player. On that game object, I then put a sphere collider so that it would act as a radius around my player. Once doing that, I changed the code to say

```
     `OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
      if(other.tag == ("Item") {} `
```

In the If statement, I included the code to check if the item is available in the availableItemsList.

Comment: Noice, sometimes it helps just to post a question - in the few times I've posted a Q on here I've worked it out within a few minutes!